# which watermark strategy does flink use when define watermark in flink sql ddl

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#defining-in-ddl

It says:

```
CREATE TABLE user_actions (
  user_name STRING,
  data STRING,
  user_action_time TIMESTAMP(3),
  -- declare user_action_time as event time attribute and use 5 seconds delayed watermark strategy
  WATERMARK FOR user_action_time AS user_action_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) WITH (
  ...
);

SELECT TUMBLE_START(user_action_time, INTERVAL '10' MINUTE), COUNT(DISTINCT user_name)
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY TUMBLE(user_action_time, INTERVAL '10' MINUTE);
```

I would ask which watermark strategy it is using? `PunctuatedWatermarks`(generate watermark immediately for new record) or `PeriodicWatermarks`(generate the watermark periodically, 200ms by default.)

Is it possible that I can choose the watermark strategy(Punctuated or Periodic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink SQL is using a periodic watermark strategy. You can configure idleness detection by setting `table.exec.source.idle-timeout` ([docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-source-idle-timeout)).

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/config/#overview for info on how to set per-job and per-cluster configuration options.

Support for the missing features (such as punctuated watermarking) is being designed and discussed right now. See [FLIP-296: Extend watermark-related features for SQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-296%3A+Extend+watermark-related+features+for+SQL) and https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@flink.apache.org/msg64425.html.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use the datastream API to establish the watermarking you want, and then have the Table API use those watermarks coming from upstream, e.g.:

```java
Table table =
    tableEnv.fromDataStream(
        dataStream,
        Schema.newBuilder()
            .columnByMetadata("rowtime", "TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)")
            .watermark("rowtime", "SOURCE_WATERMARK()")
            .build());
```